# Catching wrong database credentials using VBA to oracle database

Tags: excel, database, vba, oracle, user-experience

I have an Excel-based reporting tool that connects to an oracle database to run canned reports and return the results in a new spreadsheet. I don't have any problem connecting to the database or running my reports. Database credentials are provided via a userform each time a report is needed. I see this question asked in many different ways but no real answer so I'll try to be clear.

**Current Behavior**

1. User provides incorrect database credentials
2. System box pops up with fields for username, password, and server with "Ok" and "Cancel" button

Excel doesn't catch this as an error so I can't use normal error handling.

**Desired Behavior**

1. Excel catches the incorrect credentials reported back from the oracle database before the system message pops up
2. If that happens, I can present the user with my custom error message and branded userform.

I'm just trying to avoid the system message for user experience reasons. Should I try to authenticate with the database and assess the response? Any help would be appreciated! I'm not sure if there is any code I can share that would be helpful.

Updated with a code snippet and workflow:

1. User click Create Report button
2. User is presented with userform with 3 dropdowns
3. User picks application (let's call this variable app) from 1st dropdown
4. User picks report type (let's call this variable reportType) from 2nd dropdown
5. User picks report from (let's call this variable report) 3rd dropdown
6. User clicks Submit button
7. User provide username and password in second userform
8. User clicks Submit button

A few things to know about the code snippet below:
dbProvider is OraOLEDB.Oracle.
pw is provided by the user through the userform in step 7.
un is provided by the user through the userform in step 7.
database is stored in the macro itself by application on another tab. The macro looks up the databases for the respective application picked by the user.
wsData is just a tab in my spreadsheet where the result of the query is displayed.

userQuery is created based on the app, reportType, and report picked by the user. I have a few custom functions that build queries based on what the user picked. I don't have any issues with these and they run fine.

This is how Excel connects to the oracle database.

```
With wsData.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=" & dbProvider & ";Password=" & pw & ";User ID=" & un & ";Data Source=" & database, Destination:=wsData.Cells(lrData + 1, 1)).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = userQuery
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

This is the box that pops up that I'm trying to keep from popping up:

[Oracle Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T89j.png)

Comment: Can you show the code that is making the database connection?

Comment: I've *never* seen the behavior you're describing, so it's clearly specific to exactly how you run your queries.  Would definitely help to show your connection and query code.

Comment: I assume you created the report with some build-in functions and wizards. There you don't have much control over program behavior. You would have to write your own code in VBA, i.e. connect to database with ODBC or OLE DB (with desired handling in case of wrong credentials) fetch data from database and build the report from that data.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I've updated with some additional content, a code snippet, and an image of the box that pops up. Note that this box pops up only when the user has submitted their credentials incorrectly. Technically, VBA doesn't seem to see this as a runtime error unless I click cancel on that box. Right now I'm instructing users to click Cancel and start over.